# Are hydrogen atoms in acetone molecule acidic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds

My chemistry book says that acetone is aprotic, but I think that, since the conjugate base of acetone has possible  resonating structures, the hydrogen atom must be free to move out as $\ce{H+}$ (as the resulting structure is more stable than the previous one). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the conjugate base of [acetone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetone)?

Comment: What is the pKa of a hydrogen $\mathrm{\alpha}$ to a ketone?

Comment: @DHMO conjugate base of hydrogen is the molecule we get on removing a H+ unit from the molecule, as per my knowledge .

Comment: @zhe sorry, I haven't yet studied the concept of pKa .

Comment: You literally said that "the conjugate base of acetone has possible resonating structures". I'm asking you what "the conjugate base of acetone" is.

Comment: There are levels upon levels of wholly different meanings to the word "acidic". Yes, acetone is acidic (in a way), but not like ordinary acids. And yes, it is aprotic.

Comment: Generally, we refer to protic as meaning "can hydrogen bond." This may be a bit of an oversimplification, but it might help you understand what the problem is here.

Comment: @Ivan neretin, will u please explain what aprotic really means and/or why this compound is aprotic ?

Comment: @Dhmo, it's CH3COCH2-

Comment: You can't remove a hydrogen like this...

Comment: Why, you can, but it is pretty hard.

Comment: @Dhmo , that's what the question is . Why can't we remove the H when the resultant molecule is resonance stabilized . We can't remove it means it's aprotic

Comment: @ Ivan neretin , what makes it hard?

Comment: @PyroRecorcinol You'd better wait till you get familiar with the concept of pKa. Before that, think of it this way: there are strong acids, like H2SO4 and HCl, and there are weak acids, like H2S. Then there are even weaker acids, which are so weak that they don't work as acids in water. And then there are other acids, which are many _orders of magnitude_ weaker than that.

Comment: The point is that after removing one proton, the resulting structure is in fact not resonance stabilised. The terminal double bond of the enolate is not very favourable. If you have a tertiary C-atom there, then the enolate is sterically less hindered and has an advantage. If you have another double bond at the beta C-Atom, then you get resonance stabililsation.

Comment: When the alpha hydrogen moves out, it's the first step of tautomerism.. given the small percentage of enol form present, you can safely say it's not much acidic

Comment: With respect to a large number of other molecules, deprotonating acetone is remarkably simple. Also, I reject Ivan’s opinion that acetone be aprotic; it can very well protonate given appropriate bases.

Answer (score 2):

You’re not going wrong anywhere. Acetone can indeed be deprotonated. The resulting structure is called an enolate.

$$\ce{H3C-C(=O)-CH3 <<=> H3C-C(-O^-)=CH2}$$

When compared with truly acidic compounds such as $\ce{HCl}$ and even $\ce{NH4+}$, acetone is a very, very weak acid, though. That does not mean it should be considered aprotic. Given a strong enough base — e.g. $\ce{HMDS}$ ($\ce{(Me3Si)2N-}$) — it can be deprotonated. Weaker bases will allow for partial (but probably hardly verifiable) deprotonations.

Comment: What's the threshold for something being aprotic, then? (Where does, for example, toluene lie?)

Comment: @orthocresol Very good question! Somewhere between acetone and DMSO would be my guess so a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value of $25$~$35$. Toluene has ~$40$ so it’s definitely out.