# Acetone basicity

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Why doesn't acetone have high basicity?

[image: acetone]

The C−O bond is polar, O becomes partially negatively charged and it should attract protons, becoming a strong base.

Comment: Related: [Are hydrogen atoms in acetone molecule acidic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61505/are-hydrogen-atoms-in-acetone-molecule-acidic); [Why is acetone less acidic than cyclohexanol?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97391/why-is-acetone-less-acidic-than-cyclohexanol); [Why is the pKa of a ketone higher than of water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64686/why-is-the-pka-of-a-ketone-higher-than-of-water)

Comment: Andelisk im not asking about the acidity of hydrogens in acetone , just why the oxygen cant become a proton acceptor.

Comment: Inspired by (I think) comments to this question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119921/dna-pairs-adenine-thymine-guanine-cytosine/119924#119924

Comment: Do you have a good explanation why acetone isnt a base?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason, but I can describe the trend (source: http://cactus.dixie.edu/smblack/chem2310/summary_pages/pka_chart.pdf):

[image]

Protonated ketones have a pKa of about -7. Protonated ethers have a pKa of about -4 and protonated primary alcohols of about -2. Comparison to hydronium in water is difficult, but in DMSO, hydronium is more acidic by about 2 pKa units (source: comment by DavePhD below https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/27278/72973).

So it seems water is a little bit basic. If you replace one of the bonds to hydrogen with a bond to carbon, it becomes less basic (alcohol). If you replace the other bond to hydrogen with a bond to carbon as well, it becomes even less basic (ether and ketone).

A hand-waiving explanation would be to say the electronegativity difference between hydrogen and oxygen is higher than that between carbon and oxygen. I am not sure what to say about the difference between ethers and ketones. I think of ketones as the better hydrogen bond acceptors, and as more soluble in water (all other things being equal), so I don't have a good rationale why it would be easier for an ether to accept a proton.

Comment: And what do you mean by" protonated ketones"?

Comment: I would consider the geometry of a ketone vs an ether to perhaps explain the answer. I am pretty sure the real reason lies somewhere in the MO of the two groups (i.e. the HOMO of a ketone sits lower than an ether). However, I am not sure if it would be too rigorous to dive into that though.

Comment: @SoftwarePlayer A protonated ketone is the product of a ketone acting as a base, when a proton (or H+) attaches at the oxygen.

Comment: @SoftwarePlayer "extra oxygen atom"? Alcohols, ethers and ketones all have oxygen atoms - there is no extra oxygen.

Comment: yes you are correct i thought you meant something else